# How do I find $P(X_1\ge X_2,...,X_n)$ if all variables are independent?

Tags: probability, combinatorics, stochastic-processes, order-statistics

Specifically, I have an estimation for all $X$ where $X_i\sim\mathcal{N}\left(\mu_i,\sigma_i\right)$.

Comment: $P(X_1\geq X_2,\dots X_n)$ is meaningless.

Comment: Presumably, the $X_i$ are independent.

Comment: Do you mean $P(X_1\geq X_2\geq \dots\geq X_n)?$

Comment: I am trying to get the probability a variable X1 is the first in a drawn sample. Thinking along the likes of order statistics without i.i.d variables

Comment: @MohammedNamazi What is the difference between the two questions? What about the given answer?

Comment: @callculus In this scenario, I am aware of the variance of all variables. Just want to be aware of the formula to calc the probability of the inequality. Similar to an order statistic without i.i.d variables

Comment: @MohammedNamazi What have you done in the last year? Where is your progress?

Comment: @callculus Not there, can you point me towards some literature?

Comment: @MoNa My statistics books are all in german., sorry. You want to calculate $P(X_1>\max(X_2, X_3, \ldots, X_n))$, where $X_i\sim \mathcal N(\mu_i,\sigma_i^2)$?

Comment: @callculus exactly, https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4062324/is-there-an-easy-fast-method-for-calculating-textpx-i-textmaxx-1-do?rq=1 and https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3520600/probability-that-one-gaussian-rv-exceeds-all-others?rq=1 seem to be enough for me to chew on. Thank you for the correspondance though. Cheers!

Comment: @MoNa You're welcome. Looking forward to hear from you in 2022.

Comment: @callculus I'll take the banter. I deserve it haha